# Clases en python

Tags: python

se que esto es básico, pero podríamos decir que soy un poco nuevo en python y hay cosas que no conozco. Quiero hacer un llamado de una función dentro de otra función, todas están dentro de la misma clase. 
Ejemplo:

```
Import ClassHeredada

Class MyClass(ClassHeredada):
    def mi_funcion1(nombre):
        return nombre
    def mi_retorno(nombre):
        print mi_funcion1(nombre)
```

Me muestra este error :

```
NameError: global name 'mi_funcion1' is not defined
```

No me doy cuenta donde esta el error.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu clase `ClassHeredada`?

Comment: En realidad mi función no viene de una clase heredada, la desarrollo dentro de  MyClass y quiero usar esa función dentro de otra en la misma clase MyClass.

Comment: Ahora entendí tu problema.

Answer (score 4):

No se exactamente que es lo que pretendes hacer, pero ¿No deberian ser las dos funciones métodos de la clase? Es decir, algo asi:

```
class MyClass():
    def mi_funcion1(self, nombre):
        return nombre
    def mi_retorno(self, nombre):
        print self.mi_funcion1(nombre)

miObjeto = MyClass() #instancia de Myclass
miObjeto.mi_retorno('Pepito')
```

Notese el uso del parámetro `self` en cada método de la clase. Es una referencia al objeto cuyo método es llamado. El nombre es convencional, puede ser cualquier cosa pero se suele usar `self` por convención, de esta forma todo el mundo sabe a que hace referencia. Internamente es un puntero a si mismo (de ahí lo de 'self').

Comment: Exacto FJSevilla, después de tantas horas de código  php y luego python, no me estaba dando cuenta que no estaba haciendo referencia a los atributos de clase MyClass. Gracias a todos por sus comentarios y a @FJSevilla

Comment: @NahuelJakobson Si ha resuelto tu duda deberías marcar su respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas,después de tantas horas de código php y luego python, no me estaba dando cuenta que no estaba haciendo `referencia` a los `atributos` de la clase `MyClass`.
Es como dice `@FJSevilla`:

```
class MyClass():
    def mi_funcion1(self, nombre):
        return nombre
    def mi_retorno(self, nombre):
        print self.mi_funcion1(nombre)

miObjeto = MyClass() #instancia de Myclass
miObjeto.mi_retorno('Pepito')
```

Aca estaba mi error :  `print self.mi_funcion1(nombre)`

Comment: Deberías aceptar su pregunta en vez de crear una nueva. De esta manera los usuarios futuros podrán ver más fácilmente cual fue la solución a tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

No te faltara un `return`?

```
Import ClassHeredada

Class MyClass(ClassHeredada):
    def mi_funcion1(nombre):
        return nombre
    def mi_retorno(dato):
        print mi_funcion1(dato)
```

desde consola tienes que importar toda la `clase` asi:

```
from MyClass import *
```

Comment: No, ya lo había hecho y sigue el mismo error.

Comment: @NahuelJakobson lo importaste? edite mi respuesta

Comment: Si lo importe, pero te respondo lo mismo que puse arriba..En realidad mi función no viene de una clase heredada, la desarrollo dentro de MyClass y quiero usar esa función dentro de otra en la misma clase MyClass.